# Difference of sequences tending to infinity tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Show that if $b_k = a_k^2 - 4a_k$, then $b_k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$.

As $a_n$ tends to infinity we have that for any $K>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that $n  \ge n_0 \implies a_n> K$.

We want to show that $b_k >K$ also for any $K>0$. Now since $a_n >K$ for any $K$ when $n \ge n_0$ it must be that $a_n > \sqrt{K+4}+2$ for any $K >0$.

Thus $b_k=a_k^2-4a_k > (\sqrt{K+4}+2)^2 - 4(\sqrt{K+4}+2) = K$ whenever $k \ge K$.

Is there some conditions which I should make regarding $k$ here? I have a slight confusion with the indexes $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Should that be $b_{k+1} = a_k^2-4b_k$ or $b_k=a_k^2-4b_{k-1}$?

Comment: Hint: Use "wlog. $K>5$".

Comment: You wrote $b_k = a_k^2 - 4b_k$ in one place and $b_k = a_k^2 - 4a_k$ in another. Which is the actual question?

Comment: Can't you just write $b_k=a_k(a_k-4)$? In this way the thesis is trivial

Comment: @SilvioM I think that this requires the proof that the product of sequences tending to infinity tends to infinity as well.

Comment: Yes and this is always true (while it's not true for the difference). Regarding the product, we call $c_k:=a_k-4$; since both $a_k$ and $c_k$ tends to $\infty$, for every $M>0$ there exist a $k_a$ and $k_c$ such that $a_{k_a}>M$ and $a_{k_b}>M$ and then, taking $k_0:=\max(k_a,k_c)$, we have that $b_{k_0} > M^2$, thus it tends to $\infty$ thanks to the arbitrarity of $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting with more conventional variable names, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n = \infty$ means:
$$\forall \epsilon>0\text{ }(\exists N_{\epsilon}\in \mathbb{N}\text{ }(\forall n>N_{\epsilon}\text{ }(x_n > \epsilon))).\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }(\star)$$

---

We want to show if $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfies $(\star)$, then so does $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $b_n:= a_n^2 - 4a_n$.

---

$\underline{Proof:}$
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfies $(\star)$, we have existence of $N_{\epsilon}$ making $\color{red}{a_n > \epsilon}$ for $n>N_{\epsilon}$.
Shifting the red statement, we have:
$$a_n-4 > \epsilon -4,$$
Then since $a_n>\epsilon>0$, positive scaling gives:
$$a_n(a_n-4) > a_n(\epsilon-4)>\epsilon(\epsilon -4).$$
Rewriting, this says:
$$b_n > \epsilon^2-4\epsilon.$$
Now, define $\color{red}{\epsilon'}$ such that $(\epsilon')^2-4(\epsilon') = \epsilon$. Then by satisfaction of $(\star)$ by $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we have existence of $N_{\epsilon'}$ yielding $a_n>\epsilon'$, which as we have shown, implies $b_n > \epsilon$. We may use this $N_{\epsilon'}$ to show $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfies $(\star)$. If you like, you can make a distinction by saying $N_{\epsilon,b}:= N_{\epsilon',a}$ to show from which version of $(\star)$ it came from. $\square$

Comment: I suppose a little care should be taken assuming there exists a (positive) root of the polynomial $p(x) = x^2 - 4x - \epsilon$. @Cava it seems you algebraically found one. I was going to lean toward graphical analysis as a general approach. In this case, one can see that $x(x-4)$ is a parabola with one positive root. Subtracting positive values from the function value just shifts the parabola down and widens the intercept range (in other words there is always a positive root).

Answer (score 0):

More simply by the definition of limit we have that eventually, say for $n>n_0$, $a_n> 5$ then for $k>n_0$ we have

$$b_k = a_k^2 - 4a_k =a_k(a_k-4)>a_k$$

and we can easily conclude.

---

More rigorously we need to show that

$$\forall M, \; \exists k_0, \; b_k>M,\; \forall k>k_0$$

then set $k_0\ge n_0$ such that $\forall n>n_0$ we have $a_n>|M|+4$, therefore

$$b_k=a_k^2-4a_k=M^2+4|M|>M$$